# unable to launch new tab from right click action | Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, keyboard-events

I'm trying to right-click on a link and use the keys arrow-down and enter to open a new tab.

Problem: No error displayed during execution. The link is identified and a right-click is made on it. however, the code is not performing the down-arrow and entering the action. Can't seem to figure out why.
Can somebody help?

**Code:**

```
a.moveToElement(subfooterdriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(1)).contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

`a - obj to action class`,
`subfooterdriver - is a frame consisting of 5 links`

**Updated:**

I was able to overcome the issue with the following code but I want to understand what went wrong with the first code.

```
String clickonlink=Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.ENTER);
subfooterdriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(clickonlink);
```

Comment: Browser's context options are native elements, right? Selenium automates web pages only. You need to use libraries like Robot to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the link inside this hyper text then open it in new tab as following :

```
//element locatore
WebElement link =driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
//Get Required URL
String url = link.getAttribute("href");
```